# Display Alert Dialog only when EditText is empty.

Tags: java, android

All- I have an app in which the user inputs values into multiple edittext fields and than the user taps a button to calculate all the numeric inputs into a formula and outputs the answer. My problem is that when one of the edittect fields is left empty the app force closes when the calculate button is hit. I know I can fix this by having an alert dialog box pop up when the calculate button is hit and there are one or more empty edittext fields. I don't know how to put the alert dialog inside of an "if" statement. For example "if any one of the edittext fields are empty .show() this alert dialog". Could someone please give me some sample code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you asking for the conditions, or how to create an alert, or both...?

Comment: I don't know how to create an if statement with an alert dialog inside. I know how to create an alert dialog but I don't  know how to have it display only under certain conditions.

Comment: No offense, but it sounds like you should start with some beginner Java tutorials rather than Android development. Conditional constructs are one of the very basic building blocks of writing Java code and your question could basically be, "How do I write a condition in Java?" Once you figure that out, you can apply the principle to any code inside a condition, whether it's creating an alert or something entirely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have (or create) an array/list of all the `EditText` fields, you can run through them like this

```
for(EditText e : editTextList)
{
    if(e.getText().toString().length() == 0)
    {
        //Show dialog 
        break;
    }
}
```

You can create a list of `EditText`s like this:

```
List<EditText> editTextList = new ArrayList<EditText>();
```

and then just add

```
editTextList.add(myEditText);
```

Comment: Ok. I will try that. I am a little rusty on creating arrays. Is there any other way to do it? Thanks for answering.

Comment: You can create a list. `List<EditText> editTextList = new ArrayList<EditText>();` and then just add your `EditText`s `editTextList.add(myEditText);` EDIT: I will add it to my answer. ;)